# ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream | client that receive and send a lot of objects (Java)

Tags: java, swing, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a problem on my multithreaded server/client project.

The server side is good but the problem is on the client side.

I can send and receive objects every time I want I need to declare an `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` as attributes on my Class and then instantiate them on the constructor

But the problem is that the code is blocking on the `ObjectInputStream` instantiation.

Here is my code:

Client:

```
 public class agency_auth_gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Socket s_service;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;

    public agency_auth_gui() {
        try {
            initComponents();
            System.out.println("#Connexion en cours avec le Serveur Bancaire.");
            s_service = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6789);

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s_service.getOutputStream()));
            in= new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s_service.getInputStream()));
            //Authentification du Client GAB
            out.writeObject((String) "type:agence");
            out.flush();

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
...
Some automaticaly generated swing code
...
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // Envoi d'une arraylist exec contenant l'authentification

            ArrayList exec = new ArrayList();
            exec.add("auth_agent");
            exec.add(jTextField1.getText());
            exec.add(jTextField2.getText());
            out.writeObject((ArrayList) exec);
            out.flush();

            // Reception de la reponse du serveur pour la fonction authentification


            Agent agent = (Agent) in.readObject();
            if(agent.getId()==0)
            {
                System.out.println("null");
            }else
            {
                System.out.println(agent.getId());
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }                                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {

            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(agency_auth_gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new agency_auth_gui().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc for ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header.

**Edit**

So it appears that you're not receiving anything on the `InputStream` from the other end.

Comment: What's the relevance of the last sentence?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't make sense. I misread the example and thought the streams were piped, which they obviously don't have to be.

Comment: Understood, but how could i do what i wana do ?
How should i make my client read  and send as many objects as he want ?

Comment: When your server accepts the client, it also has to send an object in return, or it will just block.

Comment: No it doesn't. But it does have to construct an ObjectOutputStream when it accepts the socket.

Comment: Which it does by constructing the ObjectOutputStream. It's not clear to me that you really understand the issue.

Comment: I don't see any distinction between wrong conclusions and not understanding. Your remark above about pipes for example is just waffle.

Comment: Yes finaly as i said NilsH i sended an answer from the server to the client and it doent block, thx all

Comment: I'm sure this could become a very "interesting" discussion, @EJP. But I'm not taking the bait.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your server isn't constructing an ObjectOutputStream when the connection is accepted. Don't defer this step: it will block the client while constructing its ObjectInputStream. See the Javadoc.

Comment: Understood, but how could i do what i wana do ?
How should i make my client read  and send as many objects as he want ?

Comment: You have to fix the server. I don't know why this is so mysterious.